# how to add and remove classes of objects after drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running the following **html**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="container1">
            <div class="resizeDiv col-6"></div>
            <div class="resizeDiv col-6"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div id="container2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the **JS**

```
var currentParent;  
$(".resizeDiv").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  containment: "#container2",
  start: function(){
    currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  }
}); 
$('#container1, #container2').droppable({
  accept:'.resizeDiv',
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    if (currentParent != $(this).attr('id')) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
    }
    $(this).find("div").on("click", function(){
      if($(this).hasClass("col-6")) {
        $(this).removeClass("col-6").addClass("col"); 
      } else { 
        $(this).removeClass("col").addClass("col-6");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

When I `drop` one element and I `click` on it, its `class` changes from `col-6` to `col`, however when I `drop` the second item, the `toggle classes` on the `click` only works on the second added item and not the first one added.

Here it is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqbJOp), try adding one item to the second container and the click on it and then drop the second item and try to click on them.

**NOTE**

Ideally I would like to auto size without the click

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this

```
$(this).find("div").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("col-6")) {
    $(this).removeClass("col-6").addClass("col"); 
  } else { 
    $(this).removeClass("col").addClass("col-6");
  }
});
```

What this does is every time you drop an element it is going to go through ALL divs in that container. That means the ones you already set a click handler on, so when you drop a second item, the first div is going to get a second click handler. If you dropped a third it would get a third and so on.

So when you click the first one you are actually firing off two of these callbacks, and the class gets added in the first and removed in the second.

Since `ui.draggable` refers to the dragged element use that as a reference to add the click handler

```
$(ui.draggable).on("click",function(){
  let $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass("col-6")) {
    $this.removeClass("col-6").addClass("col"); 
  } else { 
    $this.removeClass("col").addClass("col-6");
  }
  //note instead of doing the if else and removeClass().addClass() 
  //calls you could just do toggleClass('col-6 col')
  //it will toggle one off and the other on
  $this.toggleClass('col-6 col');
});
```

If instead you want to get rid of the click handler and just want to add the class directly then do so on `ui.draggable`

```
$this = $(this); 
$draggable = $(ui.draggable);
if (currentParent != $this.attr('id')) {
  $draggable.appendTo($this).removeAttr('style').toggleClass('col-6 col');
}
```

Also note I am storing the jQuery objects. If you are going to use something like `$(this)` or `$(ui.draggable)` multiple times it is better to store it in a variable and use it instead of making multiple calls to `jQuery()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to use:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

[Link to doc](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/)

Final **js** code

```
var currentParent;  
$(".resizeDiv").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  containment: "#container2",
  start: function(){
    currentParent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  }
}); 
$('#container1, #container2').droppable({
  accept:'.resizeDiv',
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    if (currentParent != $(this).attr('id')) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this)).removeAttr('style');
    }
    $(this).find("div").on("click", function(e){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if($(this).hasClass("col-6")) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        $(this).removeClass("col-6").addClass("col"); 
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        $(this).removeClass("col").addClass("col-6");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**NOTE**

Yet I am still trying to `auto size` if `el` is `dropped` next to the other.